# Is there a way of displaying different slides of bootstrap carousel by adding different names to the url address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm looking at the bootstrap carousel slider http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/ and I wonder if there's a way of reaching specific slide by its name. As for now this is how I define the carousel indicators:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-orange">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" id="businessCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
```

and when I go to www.mydomain.com I always see the first slide. But is there a way of customizing it so that when user types www.mydomain.com/second he will see the webpage with second slide visible?

I tried adding `name=` to each carousel indicator but that didn't work as expected. Thanks for any clues!

Comment: Where are the docs for this plugin? A distinct lack of documentation = throw in the bin when I'm plugin shopping, and you should too. Owl carousel is a much nicer plugin than anything else I've seen on the scene. If you can find some documentation, you might find what this carousel is capable of out of the box. Otherwise you are just re-inventing the wheel potentially. Owl has the method `.goTo(x)` for exactly this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashed url in the form of

**www.mydomain.com#sdt0** *for data slide 0*

**www.mydomain.com#sdt1** *for data slide 1*

Get the location hash from the URL and the `data-slide-to` value after that

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var data-slide-to = hash.split('sdt')[1];
```

In order to make active the slide you want try this example

```
$("li[data-target=#myCarousel]")
  .removeClass("active")
  .each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("data-slide-to") == data-slide-to) {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: the closing tag is on the `.each` - that's why I indented it in that position. Nice solution by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by specifying which slide you wish to start with:

```
// parse the page number you want from window.location.href
$('.carousel').carousel(slideToStart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using hash in the adress bar. For example "www.mydomain.com/#second" with a function that after page load checks the hash and changes the active class to the second slide.

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
    hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash !== ''){//If there's a hash
        $('.carousel-inner .item .active').removeClass('active');
        $(hash).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Note: you need to add an ID to every `.item` inside of `.carousel-inner`, so the script can "activate" the `.item` that has the same ID as the hash.